# Angular dropdown default value not working

Tags: angularjs

In my angular application , I have created one dropdown containing sim name. Those names are coming from API. I also set default value as All sim. But it is not working. Here is my code snippet.

```
<select ng-model="selectSim" class="selectpicker" ng-options=" item.description for item in simList">
<option value="all">Select All</option>
```

When I I render this page , I can see dropdown containing Sim name but my "select all" option is missing.

I cant figure it out whats  wrong in my code.

Comment: Can you show me your controller code?????????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `option value = ""`

```
<select ng-model="selectSim" class="selectpicker" ng-options=" item.description for item in simList">
      <option value="">Select All</option>
</select>
```

A single hard-coded  element, with the value set to an empty string, can be nested into the  element. This element will then represent the null or "not selected" option.

Answer (score 0):

try this

This is html code (don't need `option` tag )

```
<select ng-model="selectSim" class="selectpicker" ng-options=" item.description for item in simList">
```

and write this way in your controller code where assign values to `simList`

```
$scope.simList.push({ description : "Select All", Id: 0 }); // this line helps to dynamoically add defualt value in `$scope.simList` array, now the default item added in bottom side 

  $scope.selectSim= $scope.simList[$scope.simList.length - 1];// this is helps to assign default item `selectSim` model
```

> **'*'**  here `Id: 0` is your value name and dummy values. you need to change value name